# How to enumerate all environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment

`System.getenv(name)` needs the name of environment variable.

I am trying to call `Runtime.exec(String[], String[], File),` the secondary parameter need an array of environment variable, I am not sure whether subprocess will inherit environment variables from current process if I specified this parameter.

For example, if I pass `new String[]{"NEWDIR=/home"}` as secondary parameter and current java process has environment `OLDDIR=/var`, what is the return value of `System.getenv("OLDDIR")` in the subprocess?

*updated:*
Sorry, I have to use Java 1.4 and it seems that `System.getenv()` was introduced in 1.5?

Comment: Why must you use Java 1.4? The newer versions of Java have fantastic backwards compatibility - have you tried upgrading?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`System.getenv()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) will return a `Map<String,String>` with all of the environment variables.

But you could just as easily switch to [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which is a more convenient API to start new processes.

With `ProcessBuilder` you can simply call [`environment()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29) and get a `Map` that *contains existing environment variables* and which you can *manipulate* how you want: i.e., if you add something to it, then that will be added to the new processes environment variables. If you remove something from it, it will *not* be present in the new process.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, how should I do in JAVA14?

Comment: You're pretty much screwed then, since both `System.getenv()` and `ProcessBuilder` where introduced in Java 5 only and `Runtime.exec()` doesn't allow a way to merge unknown existing environment variables with newly specified ones. Seriously: get rid of that ancient version.

Comment: Hint for current/future readers: The "JAVA 14" mentioned here referred to Java 1.4 (released in 2002) and not really to Java 14 (released in 2020). Java 14 (and later) obviously contains the "new" APIs.

Answer (score 50):

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run an external shell, you can use it to set environment variables. e.g.

```
bash -c ENV1=hi ENV2=bye echo $ENV1 $ENV2
```

This only works if you have a UNIX shell (or cygwin)

You should migrate away from Java 1.4 and Java 5.0.  Even Java 6 you might consider upgrading to Java 7.